# ipywidgets seems to use a wrong link address

Tags: python, widget

I'm trying to use an [old GitHub repository](https://github.com/stefanovic80/voila-gpx-viewer) which seems to be not supported anymore. I'm trying to upgrade and run it.

The line of code I'm interested in is as follows:

```
from ipywidgets import Button, HTML, HBox, VBox, Checkbox, FileUpload, Label, Output, IntSlider, Layout, Image, link
out = Output
out
```

Once I run it (in a much more sophisticated script, available [here](https://github.com/stefanovic80/voila-gpx-viewer/blob/master/app.ipynb)), than I get the following message of error:

---

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 13, in show_uploader.<locals>.handle_upload(change)
     11 with StringIO(gpx_content) as gpx_file:
     12     with out:
---> 13         plot_gpx(gpx_file)

Cell In[9], line 2, in plot_gpx(gpx_file)
      1 def plot_gpx(gpx_file):
----> 2     gpx = parse_data(gpx_file)
      4     stats = plot_stats(gpx)
      5     trace = plot_map(gpx)

Cell In[4], line 7, in parse_data(file)
      5 gpx = gpxpy.parse(file)
      6 elevation_data = srtm.get_data()
----> 7 elevation_data.add_elevations(gpx, smooth=True)
      8 return gpx

File ~/anaconda3/envs/voila-gpx-viewer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/srtm/data.py:230, in GeoElevationData.add_elevations(self, gpx, only_missing, smooth, gpx_smooth_no)
    227     original_elevations = list(map(lambda point: point.elevation, gpx.walk(only_points=True)))
    229 if smooth:
--> 230     self._add_sampled_elevations(gpx)
    231 else:
    232     for point in gpx.walk(only_points=True):

File ~/anaconda3/envs/voila-gpx-viewer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/srtm/data.py:267, in GeoElevationData._add_sampled_elevations(self, gpx)
    265 def _add_sampled_elevations(self, gpx):
    266     # Use some random intervals here to randomize a bit:
--> 267     self._add_interval_elevations(gpx, min_interval_length=35)
    268     elevations_1 = list(map(lambda point: point.elevation, gpx.walk(only_points=True)))
    269     self._add_interval_elevations(gpx, min_interval_length=141)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/voila-gpx-viewer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/srtm/data.py:259, in GeoElevationData._add_interval_elevations(self, gpx, min_interval_length)
    257 if no == 0 or no == len(segment.points) - 1 or length > last_interval_changed:
    258     last_interval_changed += min_interval_length
--> 259     point.elevation = self.get_elevation(point.latitude, point.longitude)
    260 else:
    261     point.elevation = None

File ~/anaconda3/envs/voila-gpx-viewer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/srtm/data.py:59, in GeoElevationData.get_elevation(self, latitude, longitude, approximate)
     58 def get_elevation(self, latitude, longitude, approximate=None):
---> 59     geo_elevation_file = self.get_file(float(latitude), float(longitude))
     61     #mod_logging.debug('File for ({0}, {1}) -> {2}'.format(
     62     #                  latitude, longitude, geo_elevation_file))
     64     if not geo_elevation_file:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/voila-gpx-viewer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/srtm/data.py:84, in GeoElevationData.get_file(self, latitude, longitude)
     82     return self.files[file_name]
     83 else:
---> 84     data = self.retrieve_or_load_file_data(file_name)
     85     if not data:
     86         return None

File ~/anaconda3/envs/voila-gpx-viewer/lib/python3.10/site-packages/srtm/data.py:115, in GeoElevationData.retrieve_or_load_file_data(self, file_name)
    113 r = mod_requests.get(url)
    114 if r.status_code < 200 or 300 <= r.status_code:
--> 115     raise Exception('Cannot retrieve %s' % url)
    116 mod_logging.info('Retrieving {0}'.format(url))
    117 data = r.content

Exception: Cannot retrieve http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Eurasia/N44E012.hgt.zip
```

From my understanding, the package should use a source from the internet address

http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Eurasia/N44E012.hgt.zip

which is not available anymore, as if I try to access to it I get this

[image]

Googling "N44E012", I've got this

https://step.esa.int/auxdata/dem/SRTMGL1/N44E012.SRTMGL1.hgt.zip

which I believe is the internet address that I need to be upgraded. Could u help me to figure out how to do it, please?